# Parse.com To Do web app deployment issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web, parse-platform, cloud

Apologies for basic question. I am very new in web development . I have download parse.com javascript web To Do App from https://parse.com/tutorials/todo-app-with-javascript . Now I want to deploy with parse.com. So that I can browse this app using http://mytestapp.parseapp.com. But when try to deploy using "parse deploy" command getting error as "Command must be run in a directory containing a Parse project."

Can you please help out me by step by step process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow [deployment rule](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code) of parse?

1. If your directory structure (from where you run command) is not as below you'll get the same error:

   `-config/
     global.json
   -cloud/
     main.js
   -public/
     index.html`
2. If the keys config/global.json do not matches to yours then also you'll error.

Comment: How to make folder structure of  to do application in this way

Comment: You don't need to, if you follow the Parse link I mentioned.

Comment: Still struggling , can you please let me know how  deploy this application (https://parse.com/tutorials/todo-app-with-javascript), its provide by parse.com as example but not able to deploy .

Comment: @bond I have same directory structure created by parse when running "parse new" on command line, but when I execute parse deploy inside my project directory it says "parse is not recognized as internal or external command". what may be the issue. I followed the steps given here [link](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code/windows) . I am running on windows. What may be the issue ?